# Float values to String in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm using PgSQL 9.1.

```
SELECT 5.1::text
```

is working fine with output `'5.1'` in PgAdmin3, but with JDBC Prepared statement EXEC SQL, the result always as `'5.0999999'`.

Of source `SELECT to_char(5.1, '9.9')` will work, however this is not what I want. I want to get `'5'` in the case of `5.0` without decimal point, so I just stay on the `::text` conversion.

My assumption is there might be some session environment settings affected to this conversion somewhere, but I can't figure out how to find.

I know this is just a silly question... please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Try to cast into numeric type first...

```
SELECT (5.1::numeric)::text
```

Please add your answer if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
select cast(5.1 as text)
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2024 for Postgres 13.2 it works best as

```
SELECT (5.1::real)::text
```

For example, let's take an field `test numeric(32,4) not null default 0`.
Then:

```
SELECT t.test FROM test_table t
-- 5.1000
SELECT t.test::text FROM test_table t
-- 5.1000
SELECT t.test::numeric::text FROM test_table t
-- 5.1000
SELECT t.test::real::text FROM test_table t
-- 5.1
```